# Using Rollup with SQL produces double results

Tags: sql, sql-server, rollup

I am running a query to try and obtain some metrics by day of week as well as a total number. I am using ROLLUP to obtain a total average for the week. However, when I do so I see that the results are doubled. The numbers are the same and I verified that they are correct. However, I would like to have it produce only Sunday-Saturday with a Total listed below. Is there a way to re-write this query to do so?

```
select DATEPART(dw,t1.Call), DATENAME(dw,t1.Call),
AVG (T1.CallSec + T1.ACWSec) AS AHT
from bm.calls t1 with (nolock)
JOIN prc.RRequest rreq
on t1.callid = rreq.t1CallID
join PRC.RRaw rraw with (nolock) 
on rreq.RoutingID = rraw.RoutingId
where t1.CallDate >= '2014-01-01'
AND rraw.RMode='Active'
GROUP BY  ROLLUP (DATEPART(dw,t1.Call)),(DATENAME(dw,t1.Call) )
```

Here is the output that I get

```
NULL    Monday  367.70605696962
NULL    Sunday  335.661825117371
NULL    Tuesday 359.261558682542
NULL    NULL    353.421450966283
NULL    Friday  361.478009630819
NULL    Saturday    354.216226822329
NULL    Thursday    330.073051380636
NULL    Wednesday   345.357746478873
1       Sunday      335.661825117371
2       Monday      367.70605696962
3       Tuesday     359.261558682542
4       Wednesday   345.357746478873
5       Thursday    330.073051380636
6       Friday      361.478009630819
7       Saturday    354.216226822329
```

Desired Output should be

```
1       Sunday      335.661825117371
2       Monday      367.70605696962
3       Tuesday     359.261558682542
4       Wednesday   345.357746478873
5       Thursday    330.073051380636
6       Friday      361.478009630819
7       Saturday    354.216226822329
NULL    NULL        353.421450966283
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Comment: @Mihai - Both the ways it will work

Comment: @GoatCO Added desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to change your `ROLLUP` to contain both fields:

```
SELECT  DATEPART(dw, t1.Call)
      , DATENAME(dw, t1.Call)
      , AVG(T1.CallSec + T1.ACWSec) AS AHT
FROM    bm.calls t1 WITH ( NOLOCK )
        JOIN prc.RRequest rreq ON t1.callid = rreq.t1CallID
        JOIN PRC.RRaw rraw WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON rreq.RoutingID = rraw.RoutingId
WHERE   t1.CallDate >= '2014-01-01'
        AND rraw.RMode = 'Active'
GROUP BY ROLLUP((DATEPART(dw, t1.Call), DATENAME(dw, t1.Call)))
```

`ROLLUP()` will add subtotal/total lines based on sets of fields included, you can combine multiple fields into one set by wrapping them in parenthesis.

So `ROLLUP(col1,col2)` will result in subtotals for each change in `col2` in addition to a grand total., while `ROLLUP((col1,col2))` will combine both columns into one set, and therefore show just a grand total.

Comment: That produces this. Again things are repeated

    1 Sunday 335.661825117371
    1 NULL 335.661825117371
    2 Monday 367.70605696962
    2 NULL 367.70605696962
    3 Tuesday 359.261558682542
    3 NULL 359.261558682542
    4 Wednesday 345.357746478873
    4 NULL 345.357746478873